How to convert SQL from left join to (+)
Could someone help me on how to convert SQL(PL-SQL) from left join to (+)?
The example of left join as below.  I wonder how to convert left join to (+) operation instead?
with a as (
  select 1 as a1, 1 as a2 from dual
  union select 1, 2 from dual
  union select 2, 1 from dual
  union select 2, 2 from dual
),
b as (
  select 1 as b1, 1 as b2, null as b3 from dual
  union select 2, 2, 1 from dual
  union select 2, 2, null from dual
)
select *
from a
left join b on a.a1 = b.b1
  and a.a2 = b.b2
  and (b.b3 is not null or b.b3 > 0)

If I do the following, the result set is different
select *
from a, b
where a.a1 = b.b1(+)
and a.a2 = b.b2(+)
and (b.b3 is not null or b.b3 > 0)

I expect to convert left join to (+) to give the same result.

Why do you need to do this? For fun, or your boss told you, or you're on a ancient Oracle version?

How is the result different exactly? Can you provide a [mcve]?

It can be simplified to where a.a1 = b.b1(+) and a.a2 = b.b2(+) and b.b3 (+) is not null (the or b.b3 (+) > 0 is redundant as b.b3 > 0 can only be true then b.b3 is not null).

not for fun, just to learn the correct way of using (+) operation in SQL.  thanks!

The correct way is to do LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

@siennx The correct way is not to use it. It's not 1992 anymore.

This is what your original query returns:
SQL> with a as (
  2    select 1 as a1, 1 as a2 from dual
  3    union select 1, 2 from dual
  4    union select 2, 1 from dual
  5    union select 2, 2 from dual
  6  ),
  7  b as (
  8    select 1 as b1, 1 as b2, null as b3 from dual
  9    union select 2, 2, 1 from dual
 10    union select 2, 2, null from dual
 11  )
 12  select *
 13  from a
 14  left join b on a.a1 = b.b1
 15    and a.a2 = b.b2
 16    and (b.b3 is not null or b.b3 > 0);

        A1         A2         B1         B2         B3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          2          2          1
         1          2
         2          1
         1          1

SQL>


Result of your attempt to switch to the old Oracle's outer join operator (+):
<snip>
 12  select *
 13  from a, b
 14  where a.a1 = b.b1(+)
 15  and a.a2 = b.b2(+)
 16  and (b.b3 is not null or b.b3 > 0);

        A1         A2         B1         B2         B3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          2          2          1

SQL>


What to do? All b columns have to have the outer join operator (see line #16):
<snip>
 12  select *
 13  from a, b
 14  where a.a1 = b.b1(+)
 15  and a.a2 = b.b2(+)
 16  and (b.b3(+) is not null or b.b3(+) > 0);

        A1         A2         B1         B2         B3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          2          2          1
         2          1
         1          2
         1          1

SQL>


Why would we even try to do this?

I've tried worse, @TheImpaler.
